# Echo out a specific word in bash

Tags: bash, text-formatting

Basically, i have a bunch of commands in bash that are asking my machine the information of it.

Like:

```
> host=$(hostname -A) 
hostname=$(hostname -I) 
Pub_IP=$(dig +short
myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com) 
Kernel_Version=$(uname -v | awk -F"Debian" '{print $2}' | cut -d ' ' -f2 | cut -d '-' -f1)
Deb_Version=$(cat /etc/debian_version)
```

I am also echoing it

```
echo $host $hostname  $Pub_IP  $Kernel_Version $Deb_Version > info.txt
```

What i need to figure out is how i can put `|` between each of the parameter.
So if i look into my info.txt file, it would look something like

```
 | debianmachine | output_of_hostname | output_of_Pub_IP |
```

Also, i might be able to do this with print?

Answer (score 4):

If you quote or escape your strings, you can include pipes:

```
echo "| ${host} | ${hostname} ..."
```

You can of course use `printf` too (I take it that’s what you’re asking about at the end of your question):

```
printf '| %s | %s | %s ...' "${host}" "${hostname}" "${Pub_IP}" ...
```

You can take advantage of `printf`’s repeating behaviour to simplify the format string:

```
printf '| %s ' "${host}" "${hostname}" "${Pub_IP}" ...; printf '|\n'
```

This will repeat the `| %s` sequence as many times as necessary, and end the line with a pipe and carriage return.

Answer (score 2):

Use `printf`:

```
printf '| %s | %s | %s | %s | %s |\n' "$host" "$hostname" "$Pub_IP" "$Kernel_Version" "$Deb_Version" >info.txt
```

The `%s` in the `printf` format string (the first argument to `printf`) are string placeholders and each of these will be replaced by the other arguments given to `printf` in turn.

Answer (score 0):

One idea may be to store all of variables in an array and print them out with desired modifications in a loop.

Though, I think more efficient and simple will be shell's string concatenation, for exaxmple:

```
echo "| $host | $hostname | $Pub_IP | $Kernel_Version | $Deb_Version |" > info.txt
```

One other way is to use a simple awk loop to procedurally create the content of file, so e.g.:

```
awk '{print "|"\
 for (i=1 ; i <= NF ; i++) \
   print " ", $i, " |"}' \
 info.txt | xargs -11 > info.txt
```

Comment: Your last command will clear `info.txt` before it starts processing it.